# Mysql check if one stored procedure is called from another

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to know if one stored procedure is called from another stored procedure in particular?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_1`(
  IN invar_one VARCHAR(32),
  OUT outvar_one VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN   
  /*I want some condition like this:*/
  IF (/*Is called from sp_2 */) THEN
    SET outvar_one = "OK";
  ELSE
    SET outvar_one = "NOT OK";
  END IF;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_2`(
  IN invar_two VARCHAR(32),
  OUT outvar_two VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN   
  CALL sp_1(invar_two,@outvar_two);
END;
```

Comment: Use routines table, check the answer below. It access the definition of procedure and check if sp_1 is used, however it does not guarantee which sp_1 is called.

Comment: I have tried your purposed answer but unfortunately this does not work as wanted. I need to be sure if  sp_1 is called from sp_2

Comment: I could not see there is data available for dependency of an object in MySQL information_schema database, May be you shall change the below condition to ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%CALL sp_1%'.l, to ensure the SP is called, until you find a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table called INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES has the content of the procedure, You can do a like clause to check if a given Stored procedure is referred there.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%sp_1%' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
    AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'sp_2';
```

Details here - [routines table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/routines-table.html)

However, this would give a count even if procedure sp_1 is commented. So have a better like condition.

This is one of the way, there may be better ways.